Very Transaction Signature in Ruby
We're building an authentication system between our server and mobile app where the user can sign a multi-wallet (their wallet and our wallet) Tx, submit it to our authentication endpoint where we counter sign it, and then verify that the signed Tx is valid before issuing an idToken.
We don't want to publish the Tx on chain, so there's no cost and also no network spam. However, we believe this would be an effective strategy for authorizing the traffic to our app server which manages resources belonging to different user's public wallet addresses.
How can we perform the validation? Are there glaring security vulnerabilities in the approach? Our server is built with Ruby.
